# How To Save CATransform3D applied on UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view(Uiview) that applied CATransform3D on it , 
I want to create a same view like that when I open app again

So I do:
save transform to use it in open app later

```
   let radian_vertical =  element.layer.value(forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.y") as? NSNumber ?? 0
    let degree_vertical = (radian_vertical.floatValue) * 180 / (Float)(Double.pi)

    let radian_horizontal =  element.layer.value(forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.x") as? NSNumber ?? 0

   let degree_hori = (radian_horizontal.floatValue) * 180 / (Float)(Double.pi)
```

But it not correct when I apply it later

```
//saved_degree_vertical and saved_degree_hori. is saved from degree_vertical and degree_hori

 let radians_verti =  saved_degree_vertical * (CGFloat)(Double.pi)  / 180
 let radians_hori =  saved_degree_hori * (CGFloat)(Double.pi)  / 180
 let rotateVertical = CATransform3DRotate(newViewContent.layer.transform, CGFloat(radians_verti), 0, 1, 0)

 let rotateHorizontal = CATransform3DRotate(newViewContent.layer.transform, CGFloat(radians_hori), 1, 0, 0)

 newViewContent.layer.transform=  rotateHorizontal
 newViewContent.layer.transform =  rotateVertical
//save degree
```

Comment: What are you asking? You want to "save" a value but in what context, persist to disk or so it can be used in another view controller or...? Have you tried anything yourself, the code that you posted seems to have very little to do with your question?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for comment. The "saveDegree" is degrees rotation that saved. when app open, I create a view and use it to set transform, do you understand?

Comment: I suggest you use [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) then for storing the property. It's commonly used in situations like this and there is plenty of info on-line on how to use it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have update my question. that can make clearly

Comment: So in the second snippet you write to `viewContent.layer.transform` twice? Only the second line should have effect on that then. Did you read documentation that what you are doing makes sense? Those properties like `transform.rotation.y` look very suspicious to me. This is a 4x4 matrix so it would be best to save all of those values and then reconstruct the matrix from them.

Comment: @MaticOblak, sorry I have updated it, I just rotation x and y. how to do that

Comment: @Anna What you are looking for is probably `CATransform3DConcat`. This function will concatenate 2 matrices. It will multiply them. Not sure what the order of multiplication is so (assuming the rest is correct) you need to either do `CATransform3DConcat(rotateHorizontal, rotateVertical)` or `CATransform3DConcat(rotateVertical, rotateHorizontal)`. The results may differ.

Comment: @MaticOblak I have tried but this way not get difference. your answer bellow is amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just some rotations you should save a whole matrix. A `CATransform3D` consists of 16 values as it is 4x4 matrix. The properties are named as `m12`, `m13`, ... , `m43`, `m44`. It also has a constructor that takes all of those properties.

You can even serialize all 16 values into a single string and then deserialize it to make it easier. See something like the following:

```
/// A method to save the current view matrix
func saveCurrentMatrix() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(serializeViewMatrix(view: viewContent), forKey: "my_saved_matrix")
}

/// A method to apply the saved matrix to current view
func loadCurrentMatrix() {
    do {
        try applyViewMatrixFromSerializedString(view: viewContent, string: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "my_saved_matrix"))
    } catch {
        if let description = (error as NSError).userInfo["dev_info"] as? String {
            print("Error occured applying saved matrix: \(description)")
        }
    }
}

/// Serializes a view.layer.transform matrix into string
///
/// - Parameter view: A view to save matrix from
/// - Returns: A string representation of the matrix. In format 1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0 ...
func serializeViewMatrix(view: UIView) -> String {
    let matrix: CATransform3D = view.layer.transform
    let values: [CGFloat] = [
        matrix.m11, matrix.m12, matrix.m13, matrix.m14,
        matrix.m21, matrix.m22, matrix.m23, matrix.m24,
        matrix.m31, matrix.m32, matrix.m33, matrix.m34,
        matrix.m41, matrix.m42, matrix.m43, matrix.m44
    ]
    return values.map { String(Double($0)) }.joined(separator: ";")
}

/// Creates a matrix from string produced by serializeViewMatrix and applies it to given view
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - view: A view to apply matrix to
///   - string: A string representing the matrix
/// - Throws: Will throw on incorrect data
func applyViewMatrixFromSerializedString(view: UIView, string: String?) throws {
    guard let string = string else { return } // Simply return if there is no string

    // Genereate 16 string componets separated by ";"
    let components = string.components(separatedBy: ";")
    guard components.count == 16 else { throw NSError(domain: "Matrix serialization", code: 400, userInfo: [ "dev_info": "Incorrect number of components for matrix. Expected 16, got \(components.count)" ]) }

    // Parse string compoenets to CGFloat values
    let values: [CGFloat] = components.compactMap {
        guard let doubleValueRepresentation = Double($0) else { return nil }
        return CGFloat(doubleValueRepresentation)
    }
    guard values.count == 16 else { throw NSError(domain: "Matrix serialization", code: 500, userInfo: [ "dev_info": "Unable to parse all values. \(components.count) out of 16 values were correctly paresed" ]) }

    // Generate and apply transform
    view.layer.transform = CATransform3D(m11: values[0], m12: values[1], m13: values[2], m14: values[3],
                                         m21: values[4], m22: values[5], m23: values[6], m24: values[7],
                                         m31: values[8], m32: values[9], m33: values[10], m34: values[11],
                                         m41: values[12], m42: values[13], m43: values[14], m44: values[15])
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! u save my life, I have took 1 days for this confused!